# Pull html element from string using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to split specific string on two parts. First part with text and second with a href element.

This is my string:

`'Some custom string: John. <a href="/rest/link">Start something</a>'`

That second part always will be a href element. I would like to get something like this:

```
content = "Some custom string: John."
link = `"<a href="/rest/link">Start something</a>"`
```

I tried following solutions:

```
link = @data.content.match("<(.*)>") <- this return ["<a href="/rest/link">Start something</a>", "a href="/rest/link">Start something</a"]
content = @data.content.replace("<(.*)>", "") <- this return the same string
```

Is it possible to get this data without regex? Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Is this CoffeeScript or JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
   var yourString = 'Some custom string: John. <a href="/rest/link">Start something</a>';

   var d = new DOMParser();
   var dom = d.parseFromString(yourString, "text/html");
   var a = dom.querySelector('a');

   var linkText = a.innerText
   var linkHref = a.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str     = 'Some custom string: John. <a href="/rest/link">Start something</a>';
var index   = str.search(/<[a-z]/i);
var content = str.substring(0, index);
var html    = str.substring(index);
```